# Android Testes Instrumentais

Tags: android, android-studio, testes, testes-funcionais

Quando começo a elaborar o teste instrumental para a MainActivity dá erro pois não reconhece essa Classe (MainActivity), como é possível verificar na imagem seguinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Li em alguns lugares que "Como os testes instrumentados são compilados em um APK (separado do APK do aplicativo), eles devem ter seu próprio arquivo AndroidManifest.xml.". Não sei se esta é a causa do meu problema.

Será que me podem ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você declarou sua classe de teste errado e o correto seria esse:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mMainActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testeAlgo() {
        // Algum teste
    }
}
```

OBS1: Nunca precisei declarar um manifesto próprio para testes.

OBS2: A declaração do package está com um espaçamento estranho no nome.

Esse link tem um ótimo tutorial de testes: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html

Comment: testei assim como sugeriu e continua a dar um erro, diz que não consegue encontrar o MainActivity @Márcio Oliveira

Comment: o erro que me dá pode ser visivel aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230672/testes-instrumentais-android-studio  @Márcio Oliveira