# Testes Instrumentais Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, testes, testes-funcionais

Ao elaborar testes instrumentais à minha aplicação android, deparo-me com um problema e não vejo o porquê de isto acontecer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque é que o MainActivity não é reconhecido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa importar, pois seus testes devem estar em: module-name/src/androidTest/java enquanto a classe MainActivity está em: module-name/src/java.

Comment: ele não me permite fazer o import, parece que ignora

Comment: eu faço o import com.example.exemplo.Activity; @Diniz e diz  que não reconhece o Activity

Comment: já consegui resolver! obrigada!